# With python what is the most efficient way to tokenize a string (SELFIES) to a list?

Tags: python, regex, string, performance, tokenize

I am currently working with SELFIES (self-referencing embedded strings, github : https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/selfies) which is basically a string representation of a molecule. Basically it is a sequence of tokens that are defined by brackets , e.g. propane would be written as "[C][C][C]". I would like to find the most efficient way to get a list of tokens like so:

```
selfies= "[C][C][C]"
tokens= some_function(selfies)
tokens 
["[C]","[C]","[C]"]
```

i already found 3 ways to do it :

1. with the "native" function  from the github (https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/selfies/blob/master/selfies/utils/selfies_utils.py):

```
def split_selfies(selfies: str) -> Iterator[str]:
    """Tokenizes a SELFIES string into its individual symbols.
    :param selfies: a SELFIES string.
    :return: the symbols of the SELFIES string one-by-one with order preserved.
    :Example:
    >>> import selfies as sf
    >>> list(sf.split_selfies("[C][=C][F].[C]"))
    ['[C]', '[=C]', '[F]', '.', '[C]']
    """

    left_idx = selfies.find("[")

    while 0 <= left_idx < len(selfies):
        right_idx = selfies.find("]", left_idx + 1)
        if right_idx == -1:
            raise ValueError("malformed SELFIES string, hanging '[' bracket")

        next_symbol = selfies[left_idx: right_idx + 1]
        yield next_symbol

        left_idx = right_idx + 1
        if selfies[left_idx: left_idx + 1] == ".":
            yield "."
            left_idx += 1


%%timeit
tokens= list(sf.split_selfies(selfies))
3.41 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Edit: "." is never present in my case and it is not considered in solution 2 and 3 for speed's sake

This is kinda slow probably because of the conversion to a list

2. One from the creator of the library (https://github.com/aspuru-guzik-group/stoned-selfies/blob/main/GA_rediscover.py) :

```
def get_selfie_chars(selfies):
    '''Obtain a list of all selfie characters in string selfie
    
    Parameters: 
    selfie (string) : A selfie string - representing a molecule 
    
    Example: 
    >>> get_selfie_chars('[C][=C][C][=C][C][=C][Ring1][Branch1_1]')
    ['[C]', '[=C]', '[C]', '[=C]', '[C]', '[=C]', '[Ring1]', '[Branch1_1]']
    
    Returns:
    chars_selfie: list of selfie characters present in molecule selfie
    '''
    chars_selfie = [] # A list of all SELFIE sybols from string selfie
    while selfie != '':
        chars_selfie.append(selfie[selfie.find('['): selfie.find(']')+1])
        selfie = selfie[selfie.find(']')+1:]
    return chars_selfie

%%timeit
tokens= get_selfie_chars(selfies)
3.44 µs ± 43.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Which surprisingly take the same amount of time roughly that the native function

3. My implementation with a combinaison of list comprehension,slicing and .split()

```
def selfies_split(selfies):
    return [block+"]" for block in selfies.split("]")][:-1]


%%timeit
tokens=selfies_split(selfies)
1.05 µs ± 53.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

My implementation is roughly 3 fold faster but I recon that the most efficient way to tokenize is probably to use regex with the package re but i have never used it and i am not particularly confortable with regex. So I fail to see how to implement it in way that yield the best results.

Edit:

4. Suggested from answers:

```
def stackoverflow_1_split(selfies):
    atoms = selfies[1:-1].replace('][', "$").split("$")
    return list(map('[{}]'.format, atoms))
%%timeit
tokens=stackoverflow_1_split(selfies)
1.75 µs ± 101 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Without the list conversion , it is actually faster then my implementation ( 575 ns +/- 10 ns) but the list is a requirement

5. Second suggestion from answers:

```
import re
def stackoverflow_2_split(selfies):
    return re.findall(r".*?]", selfies)

%%timeit
tokens=stackoverflow_2_split(selfies)
1.81 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Surprisingly re does not seem to outperform other solutions

5. third suggestion from answers :

```
def stackoverflow_3_split(selfies):
    return selfies.replace(']', '] ').split()
%%timeit
tokens=stackoverflow_3_split(selfies)
485 ns ± 4.04 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

This is the fastest solution so far , which is  roughly 2 time faster then my implementation, Well done Kelly!

Comment: Solutions 2 and 3 don't support dots, do they? So they're wrong?

Comment: Well in that particular situation that wouldn't be a problem as a . is used to indicate a salt ( 2 compounds together)  and that scenario is not possible in my case and in the case of solution 2

Comment: Hmm ... I know Python and possibly have a faster solution, but I'm not going to research SELFIES and your case just to know exactly what is and isn't allowed...

Comment: And it would be useful to know why you need this faster than a microsecond. Do you have many such small inputs, or do you have much larger inputs?

Comment: Okay, the "."  is the only exception  as it is for a very specific case that cannot occur in my case. I have edited my post to specify it. I am doing a genetic algorithm so my SELFIES will have a mean size of roughly  50 tokens and a generation would be a group of 1 millions SELFIES.

Comment: 50 is already quite different from 3. I can easily imagine one solution being faster for 3 but slower for 50. I'd do benchmarks with realistic data.

Comment: i) Regex is notoriously known to be costly, so do not be surprised. ii) you may not need the list conversion depending on what you do. iii) Kelly's approach is indeed the smartest, depending on the stability/sanity of your strings generation/representations. Do not forget to tick his answer as correct; newcomers often forget to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another:

```
selfies.replace(']', '] ').split()
```

Benchmark with 50 tokens (since you said that's your mean):

```
7.29 us  original
3.91 us  Kelly       <= mine
8.06 us  keepAlive
8.87 us  trincot
```

With your `"[C][C][C]"` instead:

```
0.87 us  original
0.44 us  Kelly
0.88 us  keepAlive
1.45 us  trincot
```

Code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZLdSsMwFMfv@xSHwUgya90cigyGeO0jlFKy7WTGpUlJM3GIzz6TJe02NTclyf/jd0Lbg3szev7U2uNRWNOAkw1KB7JpjXVgsUXusmGXZRsUYKzcSs0V7VAJiR1bZOCXRbe3GsqVMuvdzagagTAWTjuQGpK46FolHfXXrCoXt7MqZr6iUof/A3ujh1F8jZRUJAdSAWEpi8WIHWL7ouQH/orhzjQdLPucchZak5VUJWFX9IKUX/y7Iid4HsBP/oTprNRr41LDNafFQki94UpROyomz9UoT50eUASC/uHyOG5@Rs775CxLmF5OSPFupKYBSfZIMiBZrrdIH6bMJ@Nni2t3kT6MnwW9CHrRRdLWlzgqBgUslxD9OYiirjVvsK4DrnfW56Y5u/THB/sTHpbeNyu0HmY2nU6H00DX@EHi70QVb1YbvoAzR56My/hhDO7SyZARq8m4uBew74DAGKiDCczwkV3BH48/)):

```
from timeit import repeat
import re

def original(selfies):
    return [block+"]" for block in selfies.split("]")][:-1]

def Kelly(selfies):
    return selfies.replace(']', '] ').split()

def keepAlive(selfies):
    atoms = selfies[1:-1].split('][')
    return [f'[{a}]' for a in atoms]

def trincot(selfie):
    return re.findall(r".*?]", selfie)

fs = original, Kelly, keepAlive, trincot

selfies = ''.join(f'[{i}]' for i in range(50))

expect = original(selfies)
for f in fs:
    print(f(selfies) == expect, f.__name__)

for _ in range(3):
    print()
    for f in fs:
        number = 1000
        t = min(repeat(lambda: f(selfies), number=number)) / number
        print('%.2f us ' % (t * 1e6), f.__name__)
```

Answer (score 2):

With regex you can do it as follows:

```
import re

def get_selfie_chars(selfie):
    return re.findall(r".*?]", selfie)
```

If a point should be a separate match then:

```
    return re.findall(r"\.|.*?]", selfie)
```

Comment: How could your approach be faster than `str.split` or even `str.replace` approaches, especially by costly instanciating the underlying `re.Pattern` object repeatedly (?)

Comment: In Python regexes are cached. It is only compiled once. `replace` is not going to help when the result must be a list.

Comment: Did not know that +1. Still costly aren't they ?

Comment: The cache lookup etc overhead is still fairly costly, though. For short strings it can be significant.

Comment: The `replace` does help, it's what allows the simple `split` to work.

Comment: Sure, but then you have that second pass with `split`. As you know, in Python it's all about avoiding multiple function calls and divert the work as much as possible to the underlying implementation.

Comment: I'm not worried about the two passes, simple string functions tend to be extremely fast. Quite possibly much faster than one regex pass. It's two function calls, yes, but I suspect that's not that bad, either.

Comment: To focus on the passes instead of setup overhead, I also tried my answer's benchmark with a length of 50000 tokens. The regex solution took almost three times as long as the replace+split solution.

Comment: Good job, Kelly!

Answer (score 0):

What about doing

```
>>> atoms = selfies[1:-1].split('][')
>>> atoms
["C","C","C"]
```

Assuming you do not need the square brackets anymore. Otherwise, you could ultimately do

```
>>> [f'[{a}]' for a in atoms]
["[C]","[C]","[C]"]
```

Comment: Yep, similar to my `selfies.replace(']', '] ').split()`. Can't tell whether either is correct.

Comment: How fast are your solutions compared to the question's? The question is specifically about efficiency, and you're not even talking about that at all...

Comment: There is actually no need for replacement. See edit. I am on my phone, hard to `timeit`. @KellyBundy. It will for sure be faster than any loop-based approach.

Comment: I'm on my phone as well, still do benchmarks all the time (usually on TIO.run).

Comment: TIO.run is very nice @K.

Comment: i do need the square brackets,  and  I have just tested your solution and the problem is that i return a map and the conversion to a list make it slightly slower than my solution : 1.75 µs ± 101 ns per loop